# Importing Spark libraries using Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I would like to use spark SQL in an Intellij IDEA SBT project.

Even though I have imported the library the code does not seem to import it.

Spark Core seems to be working however.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a `DataFrame` from a scala `List[A]`. You need first to create an `RDD[A]`, and then transform that to a `DataFrame`. You also need an `SQLContext`:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .setAppName("test")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val test = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4)).toDF
```

Comment: Thanks In Spark 2.0 it is possible to create a DF directly it's the sql context which caused the problem.

Comment: @ulrich The shell creates an implicit `SQLContext` for you.

Answer (score 0):

For reference this is how the Spark 2.0 boilerplate with spark sql should look like:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

 object Test {    
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("some name")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    }
}
```